# Flow: How to build a type-safe dynamic action generator

Tags: redux, flowtype

**Update at the bottom**

I'm learning Flow and trying to come up with a good way to deal with API responses in a type-safe way. I'm using an API middleware where you dispatch an action `{ type: 'API', payload: { url, next: func } }` and the middleware makes the API call and calls next.

I'm struggling to come up with a way to dynamically create next actions that perform validation.

My actions look like this:

```
type Action =
  | { type: "API", payload: apiPayload }
  | { type: "LOADED_TODOS", payload: Array<Todo> }
  | { type: "LOADED_ALBUMS", payload: Array<Album> }
  | { type: "LOADED_ALBUM", payload: Album };
```

Calling the API:

```
// action gen for response, this is what I'd like to generalize
const loadedTodos = (payload): Action => {
  const validData: Array<Todo> = validate(todosSchema, payload);
  return {
    type: "LOADED_TODOS",
    payload: validData
  };
};

const getTodos = (): Action => ({
  type: "API",
  payload: {
    url: "todos",
    next: loadedTodos
  }
});
```

I would like to replace loadedTodos() with a dynamic generator. I've tried many things but here's pseudocodeish idea (`Node<*>` is from validated package):

```
function createAction<RT>(type: string, schema: Node<*>): (mixed) => Action {
  return function(payload: mixed): Action {
    // This throws if validate() fails. Otherwise we get a "good" payload
    const validData: RT = validate(schema, payload);
    return {
      type,
      payload: validData
    };
  };
}
```

Goal being that I do not have to write an action generator for each and every API response.

Complete, runnable example that shows all types and "validated" schemas used: https://github.com/pasih/flow-api-example/blob/master/src/index.js

**Update 20 Apr 2017**

I have made some progress.

I now have:

```
const getTodos = (): Action => ({
  type: "API",
  payload: {
    url: "todos",
    next: (payload: mixed, error?: boolean, meta?: mixed): Action => ({
      type: "LOADED_TODOS",
      payload: payload instanceof Error
        ? payload
        : validate(todosSchema, payload),
      meta,
      error
    })
  }
});
```

This is close to what I want. Now I can write getAlbums(), updateWombat() etc. with "API" action and specify next payload (i.e. what to call when the API call is done) fairly succinctly. I'd still prefer to specify "next" more conveniently:

```
  ...
  url: "X",
  method: "GET",
  next: nextActionFactory("LOADED_TODOS", schemaType)
```

But I'm not sure this is actually doable with Flow.

Updated code: https://github.com/pasih/flow-api-example/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: you seem to be on the right track - you just need your validate function to return type `RT` which means your schema system needs to be integrated with your type system. for example, if you run validate(albumSchema) you'd need your validate function to have a type signature that indicates it returns an album type. you may need  to write the validation/object mapping functions yourself to get that to work.

Comment: I guess there's always going to be **some** boilerplate involved. After all generics aren't templates. I'll just have to figure out a way to do this so that I can do "myValidateFunc(schemadef)" and get back a flow-typed object that conform to schemadef. This way I don't have to write a separate validate func for every action.